# How to give input to a process builder

Tags: java, python, io, inputstream, user-input

In my program, I am running a command using Processbuilder.

The command is actually to execute python script. whatever the script printing, I am just showing it into the console by printing the input stream.

the problem is, inside the python script there is an if-condition the condition excepts Yes or No to continue the script.

I don't know how to give input Yes or No in-process builder.

Please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: Write to the `Process`'s `OutputStream`

Comment: @MadProgrammer how to do that?

Comment: How do you normally write to an `OutputStream`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I tried it is not working.

Comment: @MadProgrammer acttually the while loop in the inputstreams stops before the line for which i have to give input.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is using `inheritIO()`. 
With this option, you can use the java console as stdio for your python program. Your java program will run the python code and console used for both java and python program, so you can give input via java console.

```
ProcessBuilder test = new ProcessBuilder("python", PATH_OF_YOUR_PY_PROGRAM); 
test.inheritIO(); 
Process process = test.start(); 
process.waitFor();
```

notice: `inheritIO()` uses the console for both input and output so by activating this option the whole python output will print in java console too.